# How can I create a new node with a link/href?

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

I need to create a `<base href='http://url.com'>` node inside `<head>`.  I can add other types of nodes as shown in the Nokogiri documentation, but can't figure out how to add an `href`.  How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to access the link with `base['href']` as follows:

```
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open('http://www.site.com'))
head = doc.at_css('head')
base = Nokogiri::XML::Node.new "base", doc
base['href'] = 'http://www.site2.com' 
head.add_child(base)
```

Comment: @MarkThomas Thanks for pointing this out! I forgot to uncomment it.  I had put that there when I had code in the question before I figured out the answer and pasted it.  Editing to remove.